# Twisted custom CancelledError

Tags: python-2.7, twisted, twisted.internet

Is there a way in Twisted (Python2.7) to specify a custom exception when cancelling a deferred (possibly inheriting from CancelledError), to allow trapping only this specific type of failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the default behavior for a `Deferred` is to call `errback` with a `CancelledError` exception. You can always modify this default by providing the [`canceller`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.5.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html#__init__) callable when initializing a `Deferred` and manually call `errback` (or whatever you want) with your custom exception.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed, I had noticed the canceller in the definition of the deferred class, but was not sure at which point it was being invoked at.